# PANDAS dataframe concat and pivot data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm leaning python pandas and playing with some example data. I have a CSV file of a dataset with net worth by percentile of US population by quarter of year.
I've successfully subseted the data by percentile to create three scatter plots of net worth by year, one plot for each of three population sections. However, I'm trying to combine those three plots to one data frame so I can combine the lines on a single plot figure.

Data here:
https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/z1/dataviz/download/dfa-income-levels.csv

Code thus far:

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
# importing numpy as np
import numpy as np
 
df = pd.read_csv("dfa-income-levels.csv")
df99th = df.loc[df['Category']=="pct99to100"]

df99th.plot(x='Date',y='Net worth', title='Net worth by percentile')

dfmid = df.loc[df['Category']=="pct40to60"]

dfmid.plot(x='Date',y='Net worth')
dflow = df.loc[df['Category']=="pct00to20"]

dflow.plot(x='Date',y='Net worth')

data = dflow['Net worth'], dfmid['Net worth'], df99th['Net worth']
headers = ['low', 'mid', '99th']
newdf = pd.concat(data, axis=1, keys=headers)
```

And that yields a dataframe shown below, which is not what I want for plotting the data.

```
    low mid 99th
0   NaN NaN 3514469.0
3   NaN 2503918.0   NaN
5   585550.0    NaN NaN
6   NaN NaN 3602196.0
9   NaN 2518238.0   NaN
... ... ... ...
747 NaN 8610343.0   NaN
749 3486198.0   NaN NaN
750 NaN NaN 32011671.0
753 NaN 8952933.0   NaN
755 3540306.0   NaN NaN
```

Any recommendations for other ways to approach this?

Comment: I've edited your linked to include the income-levels.csv. waiting for approval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#filter you dataframe to only the categories you're interested in
filtered_df = df[df['Category'].isin(['pct99to100', 'pct00to20', 'pct40to60'])]
filtered_df = filtered_df[['Date', 'Category', 'Net worth']]

fig, ax = plt.subplots() #ax is an axis object allowing multiple plots per axis
filtered_df.groupby('Category').plot(ax=ax)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the categories mentioned in your code in the csv file you shared. In order to concat dataframes along columns, you could use `pd.concat` along `axis=1`. It concats the columns of same index number. So first set the `Date` column as index and then concat them, and then again bring back `Date` as a dataframe column.

- To set `Date` column as index of dataframe, `df1 = df1.set_index('Date')` and `df2 = df2.set_index('Date')`
- Concat the dataframes `df1` and `df2` using `df_merge = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)` or `df_merge = pd.merge(df1,df2,on='Date')`
- bringing back `Date` into column by `df_merge = df_merge.reset_index()`